# Model created in Blender, imported to JME3, not visualizable in SceneComposer

Tags: animation, import, blender, jmonkeyengine

I followed these instruction to create the Blender model, the output shown below: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/piXv9.png

I import the blender file, it shows up fine in the Import wizard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaVNf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8legp.png

When I go to open SceneComposer, I don't see the model there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH6iX.png

Is there something I need to do to make it visualizable? Did I make the model incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking the light bulb icon in the top left of the window. This activates the camera light.
This is a good source of tutorials for the SDK: http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/sdk